# change image sourse onclick a link in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn__close").click(function(){
    $(".sec4").hide();
   });
   $(".sec3__bx .preview").click(function(){
    var imgurl = $(".sec3__bx img").attr('src');
    $(".sec4__img").attr('src' , imgurl);
    $(".sec4").show();
   });
  });
```

```css
.sec3__bx{
   background-color: white;
   padding: 10px;
  }
  .sec3__bx--item{
   background-color: #CAD3C8;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .sec3__bx--item,.sec3__bx--item a{
   color: #535c68;
  }
  /**secttion4**/
  .sec4{
   position: fixed;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   z-index: 999;
   display: none;
  }
  .btn__close{
   position: absolute;
   right: 50px;
   top: -40px;
  }
  .btn__close i{
   font-size: 23px;
   background-color: white;
   width: 45px;
   height: 45px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 45px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  .sec4__img{
   display: block;
   width: 60%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid  bg-light">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row pt-4 pb-4 row1">
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src="https://ni.scene7.com/is/image/ni/cDAQ_16x9" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src=" https://www.goodmanmfg.com/images/librariesprovider6/resized-images/gdm-indoor-air-quality.png" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src="https://adn-static1.nykaa.com/media/catalog/product/k/a/kajal_5.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src="https://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2018/02/19/Pictures/_0b5df294-1575-11e8-a4d7-7f47b8de9439.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <!--section4-->
 <div class="sec4">
  <div class="btn__close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
  <img class="img-fluid sec4__img" src="img/s2.jpg">
 </div>
```

There  i  make  a  list  of  product , So  when  i  click  on  view  image icon , image  src  change  with  my  hide  image src . 
but  when  i  choice  different  image  it  not  change  the  image  src  with  my  hide  image  src. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .. . . . . . . . . . .

Comment: Use **$(this)** in var imgurl = $(this).parent().parent().find('img').attr('src');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this)` in `var imgurl = $(this).parent().parent().find('img').attr('src');`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".btn__close").click(function(){
    $(".sec4").hide();
   });
   $(".sec3__bx .preview").click(function(){
    var imgurl = $(this).parent().parent().find('img').attr('src'); 
    $(".sec4__img").attr('src' , imgurl);
    $(".sec4").show();
   });
  });
```

```css
.sec3__bx{
   background-color: white;
   padding: 10px;
  }
  .sec3__bx--item{
   background-color: #CAD3C8;
   text-align: center;
  }
  .sec3__bx--item,.sec3__bx--item a{
   color: #535c68;
  }
  /**secttion4**/
  .sec4{
   position: fixed;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
   box-shadow:0px 0px 0px 100px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
   z-index: 999;
   display: none;
  }
  .btn__close{
   position: absolute;
   right: 50px;
   top: -40px;
  }
  .btn__close i{
   font-size: 23px;
   background-color: white;
   width: 45px;
   height: 45px;
   border-radius: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   line-height: 45px;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  .sec4__img{
   display: block;
   width: 60%;
   margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container-fluid  bg-light">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row pt-4 pb-4 row1">
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src="https://ni.scene7.com/is/image/ni/cDAQ_16x9" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src=" https://www.goodmanmfg.com/images/librariesprovider6/resized-images/gdm-indoor-air-quality.png" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src="https://adn-static1.nykaa.com/media/catalog/product/k/a/kajal_5.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <!--col-->
    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
     <div class="sec3__bx">
      <img src="https://www.hindustantimes.com/rf/image_size_960x540/HT/p2/2018/02/19/Pictures/_0b5df294-1575-11e8-a4d7-7f47b8de9439.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="pro__img">
      <div class="sec3__bx--item p-2">
       <h4>Product Name</h4>
       <p>Buisness Volume: 0</p>
       <p>Sales Price: 0</p>
       <a class="preview" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> View</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
  <!--section4-->
 <div class="sec4">
  <div class="btn__close"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
  <img class="img-fluid sec4__img" src="img/s2.jpg">
 </div>
```